# Point multiple TLDs to one node server

Tags: node.js, apache

How would be the best way to configure multiple TLDs in NodeJS per the below example, so that I can have the node server load e.g. /myfolder when a certain host name e.g. www.domain.com hits my web server? I currently use Express for node web servers.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why would the directory matter when using Node?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I'll say this can lead to some issues from the user experience perspective unless you're really diligent about branding each site.  You're almost always going to be better off maintaining them as separate Node apps as well.  That said, it's certainly possible with [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) to set up a reverse proxy pointing to your running node app.

Check the docs on how to setup proxy-specific headers and stuff (e.g. if you want to pass along static files location if it's not hard-coded in your node app) if you need them.

Something like this:

```
ProxyPass / http://your.node.app/
```